# Oracle sql math calculation using current and previous row values

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following table:

```
ID  A   B   C
1   1   23  22
2   2   19  20
3   5   18  15
4   3   12  12
```

Columns A and B are constants. I want to calculate column C using the following formula:

for the first row

```
 C = B - A
```

after that

```
 C = previous(C) - A
```

I want to achieve this using only `oracle` `SQL`.

Comment: What is the row order? Because database can retrieve rows in any order.

Comment: @GurwinderSingh I believe a safe assumption would be by `ID`.

Comment: I added an ID column, for the row order

Comment: What do you like to get for the first row? There is no "previous".

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit for the first row, column C should be B-A

Comment: Please update your question to add in the results that you are expecting to see for the input data.

Comment: If 'C = previous(C) - A' then what purpose for storing 'B' values for rows that aren't first?

Comment: @Boneist columns ID, A, B are the input and column C is what i want to get

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you put your data in the form of

```
    A    B       C
   a1   b1   b1 - a1     == b1 - a1
   a2   b2   c1 - a2     == b1 - a1 - a2 
   a3   b3   c2 - a3     == b1 - a1 - a2 - a3
   a4   b4   c3 - a4     == b1 - a1 - a2 - a3 - a4
   ...
   an   bn   cn-1 - an   == b1 - a1 - a2 - ... - an
```

you can easily find a solution in *analytic functions*, e.g.

```
select A,
       B, 
       first_value(B) over(order by id) - sum(A) over (order by id) C
  from myTable
```

Please, check *actual order* (I've put `order by id`)

Comment: rats, I was 16 seconds too slow! *{;-)  P.s. I think it's `(order by id)`

Comment: @Dmitry Awesome

Comment: @Dmitry - Thanks for the clear breakdown, Am struggling with something similar and your explanation nailed it for me. I was able to use the logic to breakdown my formula and get it working.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Oracle analytical functinos. https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/lag-lead-analytic-functions

In your case, you are trying to compute column C, which is a derived column and previous value of such derived column can not be referenced directly in formula for `LAG` function.

So, trick is to use definition of column C to derive each row. in row 3, value of `C` should be `C@row2 - A@row3 = C@row1 - (A@row3 + A@row2) = C@row1 + A@row1 - sum(a @ row1,2,3)`, this is not sql syntax, I'm just trying to explain you algorithm

When you attempt to write same using Oracle sql, query should look like

```
SELECT ID,A,B, (LAG(C_+A,RN-1,0) OVER (ORDER BY ID)) - SUM(A) OVER (ORDER BY ID) as c FROM(
  SELECT ID, A, B, B-A AS C_, ROWNUM RN FROM TEST
)
```

Assuming table name is `TEST` and column names as `ID, A, B`

result will look like

```
ID  A   B   C
1   1   23  22
2   2   19  20
3   5   18  15
4   3   12  12
```